# Not sure how to implement a Constructor and then call it via instance

Tags: c#

Okay, so I have a couple of questions. Let me first explain what I have to do. I made this code first, but without the constructor and the two methods had static in their declaration. Now I want to add a constructor that I was provided and I have to make it's instance in the main method, and afterwards provide it with some random values. I also need to call the two methods via an instance in the Main method. At the end, after compiling, it's supposed to say "Hello World!" and "81" So here come the questions:

1. Are the variables in the constructor supposed to be the named the same as the ones in the methods?
2. How do I create an instance of the constructor in the main method?
3. How do I give it some random values?
4. How do I call the two methods via their instances?

The code:

```
namespace CalculatorA
{
    class Calculator
    {
        public string WriteText(string parametar1)
        {
            return parametar1;
        }

        public int WriteNumber(int parametar2)
        {
            return parametar2;
        }

        public Calculator(int operand1, int operand2)
        {
            this.operand1 = operand1;
            this.operand2 = operand2;
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string s = Calculator.WriteText("Hello World!");
            Console.WriteLine(s);

            string n = Calculator.WriteNumber(53 + 28).ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(n);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question 1:**
Yes and No - Yes because they can be named similarly or identically and still function because of their scope. No because in your example code you would want them to represent what values they'll be holding so you can, at a glance, understand their purpose. For simplicity, in the examples I display I will keep them as named in your example.

I suggest googling Scope and lifetime of Variables and Naming Conventions.

Also, it would be wise to apply either fields or properties to your `Calculator` class so the constructors values are stored for use by the methods within the class. Should this be your intent for the parameters.

**Question 2:**
Create an instance of the `Calculator` `class`

```
var calc = new Calculator(); //calc can be named to anything you want.
```

**Question 3:**
Using a instance of `System.Random` then producing a variety of random numbers like so.

```
var rnd = new Random();
var randomNumber1 = rnd.Next(0, 100);
var randomNumber2 = rnd.Next(0, 100);

//then using those in your Calculator.WriteNumber()
var calc = new Calculator(1,2); //without fields/properties this could be erroneous 
var result = calc.WriteNumber(randomNumber1 + randomNumber2); //returns the sum of those to params.
```

**Question 4:**
You need to initialize an instance of the `Calculator` `class` - See Question 2. Then use that variable to access the methods eg:

```
var result = calc.WriteNumber(2); //returns 2
//or
var result = calc.WriteNumber(53 + 28); //returns 81
```

Here is some working code that you can learn from example. Hope this helps.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Create random numbers
    var rnd = new Random();
    var randomNumber1 = rnd.Next(1, 100); //get a random int between 1 and 99
    var randomNumber2 = rnd.Next(1, 100); //and again

    //Create instance of Calculator Class
    var calc = new Calculator(randomNumber1, randomNumber2);

    //Intro
    string s = calc.WriteText("Hello World!");
    Console.WriteLine(s);

    //Do your addition method
    var n = calc.WriteNumber(53 + 28);
    Console.WriteLine(n);

    //Do new addition method
    var result = calc.Add(); //Returns _operand1 + _operand2
    Console.WriteLine(result);

    //exit application
    Console.ReadLine();
}

class Calculator
{
    // Set fields for your constructor to use.
    // Another valid option is using properties, google this as its beyond the scope of a basic tutorial
    private int _operand1, _operand2;

    public string WriteText(string parametar1)
    {
        return parametar1;
    }
    public int WriteNumber(int parametar2)
    {
        return parametar2;
    }

    public int Add()
    {
        return _operand1 + _operand2;
    }

    public Calculator(int operand1, int operand2)
    {
        //You don't need the this keyword
        _operand1 = operand1;
        _operand2 = operand2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. I had trouble understanding this bit. Sadly, I don't think programming is my cup of tea. This is basic stuff and I'm having real problems with it. Thank you a whole lot for your time though. I'm pretty sure this is what I was looking for.

Comment: Do you think I'd be able to contact you somehow if I have further problems? I'm trying to add some more things to this program but if I have more problems I'd like to be able to contact someone instead of making threads about basic stuff on this site. I feel like an idiot hahaha.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are lacking some object oriented programming concepts. Constructor is pretty much a method that initializes an instance of a class.

> Are the variables in the constructor supposed to be the named the same
>   as the ones in the methods?

Constructor parameters have to be named. But there is no connection between constructor params and method params. These are just separate members of a class.

> How do I create an instance of the constructor in the main method?

You create an instance of a class but not a constructor. Although construction is being called when you initiate an object using `new` keyword.

> How do I give it some random values?

Depending on the type. For integer for example you can use `new Random().Next()`.

> How do I call the two methods via their instances?

I guess... just call... Just like that:

```
calc.Method1();
calc.Method2();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The object's fields don't have to be the same as the constructor's parameters, although it is common for that to be the case.
2. `var calculator = new Calculator(53,28);`
3. Use the [`Random`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx) class
4. `calculator.WriteNumber(53+28);`

Answer (score 0):

Are the variables in the constructor supposed to be the named the same as the ones in the methods?

The variables you have used in the constructor are not declared in the class.

your class should be like this:

```
class Calculator
{
    private int operand1 {get; set;} //need to declare the var before using
    private int operand2 {get; set;}
    private string Message {get; set;}
    public string WriteText() //you don't need to send parameters to the function if you have already got them in the contructor
    {
        return Message;
    }

    public int GetSum()
    {
        return operand1 + operand2;
    }

    public Calculator(string Message, int operand1, int operand2)
    {
        this.Message = Message;
        this.operand1 = operand1;
        this.operand2 = operand2;
    }
}

class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Calculator CalcObj = new Calculator ("Hello word!", 53, 28); //That is how you can initialize a class object   
            string s = Calculator.WriteText(); //this will return you the string you passed in controller
            Console.WriteLine(s);

            string n = Calculator.GetSum().ToString(); //that will give you sum of two operand
            Console.WriteLine(n);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

For random numbers you can use 
Random() method in C# to generate random numbers in main method and pass them to the contructor of the class and GetSum will give you some of those numbers